# Android tabs with views, still dynamic

Tags: android, oop, dynamic, tabs

I want to avoid using intents in android tabs. so I am doing views, but I would like an example on how a large project does this.

Mainly because I am not just displaying static information configured on the view xml, but I am pulling a lot of information from a server when a user interacts with a button within a view. The code seems like it can get really long and messy with this view implementation, instead of when each view is in a separate activity.

I would like to see how others separated their methods in a nice neat and organized way.

and that example `hello-tabwidget` is nowhere near what I am looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a viewflipper. its like the text switcher. u put a layout inside of a viewflipper and trigger it wen a tab is selected.

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/